# Problems installing Python Pymqi package

Tags: python, windows, ibm-mq, pymqi

THis is my first post on this forum. If I am not complying with protocols, please just let me know.

```
C:\>python --version
Python 2.7.11
```

OS: Windows version 7

WMQ: 8.2

I am trying to install Python **pymqi** package. After couple hours of trying and searching the web for solutions I decided to post this question hoping to get some help. The following is the command I issue and the errors I am getting.

**C:>pip install pymqi**

```
Collecting pymqi
  Using cached pymqi-1.5.4.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): testfixtures in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from pymqi)
Installing collected packages: pymqi
  Running setup.py install for pymqi ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\reyesv~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\1\\pip
-build-4qqnkt\\pymqi\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --rec
ord c:\users\reyesv~1\appdata\local\temp\1\pip-u2jdz5-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Building PyMQI client 64bits
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pymqi
    copying pymqi\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pymqi
    copying pymqi\CMQC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pymqi
    copying pymqi\CMQCFC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pymqi
    copying pymqi\CMQXC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pymqi
    copying pymqi\CMQZC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\pymqi
    running build_ext
    building 'pymqi.pymqe' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pymqi
    C:\Users\reyesviloria362048\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DND
EBUG -DPYQMI_SERVERBUILD=0 "-Ic:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\tools\c\include" -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\python27\PC /Tcpymqi/pymqe.c /Fobuil
d\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pymqi/pymqe.obj
    pymqe.c
    pymqi/pymqe.c(240) : error C2275: 'MQCSP' : illegal use of this type as an expression
            C:\IBM\WebSphere MQ\tools\c\include\cmqc.h(4072) : see declaration of 'MQCSP'
    pymqi/pymqe.c(240) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'csp'
    pymqi/pymqe.c(240) : error C2065: 'csp' : undeclared identifier
    pymqi/pymqe.c(240) : error C2059: syntax error : '{'
    pymqi/pymqe.c(247) : error C2065: 'csp' : undeclared identifier
    pymqi/pymqe.c(247) : error C2224: left of '.AuthenticationType' must have struct/union type
    pymqi/pymqe.c(248) : error C2065: 'csp' : undeclared identifier
    pymqi/pymqe.c(248) : error C2224: left of '.CSPUserIdPtr' must have struct/union type
    pymqi/pymqe.c(249) : error C2065: 'csp' : undeclared identifier
    pymqi/pymqe.c(249) : error C2224: left of '.CSPUserIdLength' must have struct/union type
    pymqi/pymqe.c(250) : error C2065: 'csp' : undeclared identifier
    pymqi/pymqe.c(250) : error C2224: left of '.CSPPasswordPtr' must have struct/union type
    pymqi/pymqe.c(251) : error C2065: 'csp' : undeclared identifier
    pymqi/pymqe.c(251) : error C2224: left of '.CSPPasswordLength' must have struct/union type
    pymqi/pymqe.c(256) : error C2065: 'csp' : undeclared identifier
    pymqi/pymqe.c(256) : warning C4133: '=' : incompatible types - from 'int *' to 'PMQCSP'
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\reyesviloria362048\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' fa
iled with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\reyesv~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\1\\pip-build-4qqnkt\\pymqi\\se
tup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\reyesv~1\ap
pdata\local\temp\1\pip-u2jdz5-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\reyesv~1\a
ppdata\local\temp\1\pip-build-4qqnkt\pymqi\
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install [Microsoft Visual C++ compiler for Python 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266)

Comment: Laurent, I already installed Microsoft Visual C++ compiler for Python 2.7. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: BTW, easy_install also failed.

Comment: Don’t know what’s wrong. Examine the source code of this error: `pymqi/pymqe.c(240) : error C2275: 'MQCSP' : illegal use of this type as an expression:\IBM\WebSphere MQ\tools\c\include\cmqc.h(4072) : see declaration of 'MQCSP'`…

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/pymqi/mingw32.html), it seems that only MinGW32 is supported, not native Windows.